# canvas inside bootstrap modal (version 3)

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, canvas

When I put html5 canvas inside bootstrap modal, I get an undefined behavior. The objects inside the modal don't respond to time and keep getting off the 2D screen. Here is the demo:

http://projects.gasimzada.net/pacman/dev

This behavior only happens when the canvas is inside the modal window; If the canvas is in plain sight that doesn't happen... Does anyone have any experience with that? Can you please hint me to something? I am really stuck.

UPDATE: I found out that, it happens not just in Modal dialog but anything where a click would fill the canvas object with the game elements. What can cause such a strange behavior?

Comment: 2 years later and no answers :(

Comment: I have the same problem... Did you find the solution to this?

Comment: Found the answer here :D

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15626952/twitter-bootstrap-and-canvas-positioning